# How to get the DB name from table name - SQL

Tags: sql

I have 3 database which is

1. shibbir_DB1
2. shibbir_DB2
3. shibbir_DB3

Each database has **projects** table. In this table I have a **id_project** column value.

Now, how can get the **database** name based on this **id_project** value?

Any Idea?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific functionality will be needed.)

Comment: When I insert data to `projects` table it's randomly choose the DB name. So, in my application I have the `id_project` value. So I need to get the DB name based on this `id_project`

Comment: You mean you have three project tables and every one contains record with id_project = 1, right?

Comment: The answer is very database-specific. Which database are you using?

Comment: Not everyone record the same.

Comment: @Arvo random database the id_project value will be different.

Comment: @Shibbir - Could the same id-value exist in more than 1 database? Are they `IDENTITY` columns? Or `GUID`?

Comment: No same-id-value cannot be save in more than 1 database. It will be unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `SELECT DB_NAME()` to find the name of the database context your query is running in.

Example:

```
  CREATE TABLE test (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    , mydata char(1)
    , db_name sysname 
)


INSERT INTO test VALUES ('a', DB_NAME()), ('b',DB_NAME()), ('c',DB_NAME())

SELECT * FROM test
```

This should return something like the following:

```
1, a, MYDB
2, b, MYDB
3, c, MYDB
```

To do the same using an existing table, you can simply run an `ALTER TABLE` statement followed by an UPDATE to fill it in:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    , mydata char(1)
    --, db_name sysname 
)

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')

ALTER TABLE test ADD db_name sysname

UPDATE test SET db_name = DB_NAME()
```

This would return a record set identical to the one from above.

Off-topic, but this sounds like bad design.

Comment: Should I loop through all the DB connection to get the DB name?

Comment: Maybe I should add a new column that should contain the DB name, right?

Comment: @Shibbir - Based on what you shared with us so far, I'm not entirely sure. The whole use-case explanation is missing from the question.

Comment: If you have no other way of knowing the database you are in, and the ids can overlap, then yes, adding a database name would probably be solid design.

Comment: @Shibbir - I added some sample code for your reference. If this helps, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.